# Running airflow worker gives error: Address already in use

Tags: airflow

I am running Airflow with CeleryExecutor. I am able to run the commands `airflow webserver` and `airflow scheduler` but trying to run `airflow worker` gives the error: **socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use**.

The traceback:
[image]

Answer (score 11):

In the docker container running Airflow server a process was already running on the port 8793 which the **worker_log_server_port** settings in airflow.cfg refers by default. I changed the port to 8795 and the command `airflow worker` worked.
[image]

Or you can check the process listening to 8793 as: `lsof i:8793` and if you don't need that process you kill it by: `kill $(lsof -t -i:8793)`. I was running ubuntu container in docker I had to install lsof first:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install lsof
```

Answer (score 1):

See if there's server_logs process running, if so, kill it and try again.

/usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/airflow serve_logs

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and Javed's answer about changing the **worker_log_server_port** on aiflow.cfg works for me.